# SiteDefinition DocumentLibrary custom ContentType | OneDrive Syncronization

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, content-type, site-definition

I figured out a strange behavior:

I've developed a custom SiteDefinition including a custom List Instance (Document Library), which is including a custom ContentType (inheriting from document) with custom SiteColumns :)

The problem is, that I'm not able to synchronize this library with OneDrive for Business, if this library contains folders.

Error message from OneDrive:
[image: Error OneDrive]

> English: There is a problem with the element"01 Angebote -
>   Kaufmännisch". If you want to synchronize this library, you have to
>   delete this element.
>
> Error code=0x80004005; Error source=Groove

If I delete the custom ContentType from this ListInstance and add the default "Document" ContentType. Everything is working fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it!
There was no Content Type for folders. After I added this one to the library, I was able to sync.